# Permission errors

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

What file permission should I change to fix this error?

> The specified file temporary://fileo7XApl could not be moved/copied
>   because the destination directory is not properly configured.
>
> This may be caused by a problem with file or directory permissions. More information is available in the system log.
>   https://ftp-origin.drupal.org/files/translations/8.x/address/address-8.x-1.3.de.po could not be saved to translations://.

I installed Drupal 8 Open Social and tried installed some languages, but I get the following errors every time.

> [image: screenshot]

I set file permissions and ownership with `chmod -R u+rwX,go+rX,go-w /var/www/html && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html`.

Comment: Have you defined your tmp file location in Drupal and can you post a screenshot of it? Your tmp file dir is usually in /tmp or somewhere like that on the server, not in /var/www/html.

Comment: try `sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in admin/config/media/file-system you specify what the temporary file system path will be.

That path will have to be writable by your web server, in apache case it's www-data

Your best option would be to create a temporary directory that is owned by www-data

mkdir temp
sudo chown www-data:www-data temp

My structure is usually the following:

/var/www/WEBSITE/public_html/ - for the root directory

/var/www/WEBSITE/public_html/sites/default/files - for the public filesystem (this is default)

/var/www/WEBSITE/private/ - for private files directory (also writable by the web server but not accessible over the web)

and I use the generalroot /tmp , but you could put the temporary folder inside your private folder which requires no change or create an extra directory owned by www-data in

/var/www/WEBSITE/temp/

Cheers!

Comment: I will try this and update you!

Comment: @GrahamMiranda You're welcome :)